# Messages stuck in AWS SQS queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

First, some context:

I've implemented a async listener in Java for a SQS traditional queue (not FIFO), that triggers a callback each time a new message arrives at the queue. This listener is achieved using SQS JMS Library (as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html#receive-messages-asynchronously)). I'm also using the [SQS Extended Client Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html) to manage large messages (> 256KB) trough S3.

Using the SQS JMS along with the SQS Extended Client Library presents a problem: each time a large message gets into the queue and then received in the callback I've to manually get the bucket id and key to retrieve the message itself (since in the queue there's only a pointer to the S3 file with the large message).

The problem i'm facing right now is that some messages are not getting to the callback even tough they are in the queue and the receive count keeps incrementing. I really don't know what could be the problem. The only hint I have is that this messages are the one's with a pointer to a S3 file (this is not happening to all of the S3 messages, just to some of them).

What is going on?
Is it the problem that I'm using SQS JMS along with the SQS Extended Library? (Haven't found an example of this two working together in the documentation)

Comment: *if* the receive count is increasing that means your client actually receives the message and then misbehaves. You need to inspect the log for errors. This is a pure debugging problem we can right now hardly help with. Alternatively: what is the messageVisibilityTimeout of the queue and how long does your processing take?

Comment: @luk2302 The visibility timeout is set to 3 min. The process occurs in a AWS Lambda function, and that timeout works well. As you say, it needs some more debug. I will do it and comeback with a comment.

Comment: In the S3 pointer case, presumably your code is simply failing to delete the message from SQS, or it attempts to do so too late.

Comment: @jarmod I'm doing the "unpacking" of the S3 message in the listener callback. Then, I post the message data along with its receipt handle to the Lambda function that process the message and then it deletes it. This works with almost every message (S3 and no S3 message), but it fails with some of them (which coincidentally are all S3 messages)